# (Error) no matching function for call to 'Triangulo::Triangulo(int, int, int)' No logro corregir este error en mi poliformismo en C++, Dev-C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, polimorfismo

Me aparece este error al programar un a clase en C++ usando el IDE Dev-C++. Mi codigo es el siguiente y lo estoy siguiendo al pie de la letra de mi profesor en un curso de Udemy. He intentado todo lo posible y a mi cconocimiento, pero no logro superar el error. Soy bastante nuevo  en la programacion y este es mi primer proyecto de Poliformismo y no quiero avanzar sin entender que esta pasando aqui y como corregirlo en el futuro.

---

## **Main:**

Esta es la seccion de codigo donde creo los objetos y les doy forma.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Poligono.h"
#include "Rectangulo.h"
#include "Triangulo.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Poligono* poligonos[2];
    
    poligonos[0] = new Rectangulo(7,4);
    poligonos[1] = new Triangulo(3,4,4);
    
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        cout<<"Perimetro: "<<poligonos[i]->perimetro()<<endl;
        cout<<"Area: "<<poligonos[i]->area()<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

## **Clase madre, Poligono:**

Esta es mi clase madre y la que me da los atributos que mis otras dos clases deberian heredar sin problemas.

```
#ifndef POLIGONO_h
#define POLIGONO_h

class Poligono{
    public:
        virtual float perimetro()=0;
        virtual float area()=0;
};

#endif
```

## **Clase Rectangulo**

Cuando intento hacer el jercicio con mi clase rectangulo en ambas posiciones del arreglo no tengo ningun problema y me da los resultados de ambas operaciones sin error alguno, asi que es la clase Triangulo la que me esta causando el error, pero no logro descubrir porque.

```
#include "Poligono.h"

class Rectangulo : public Poligono{
    private:
        float base,altura;
    
    public:
        Rectangulo(float base, float altura){
            this->base = base;
            this->altura = altura;
        }
    
        float perimetro(){
            float per = 2*base + 2*altura;
            return per;
        }
        
        float area(){
            float area = base*altura;
            return area;
        }
};
```

## **Clase Triangulo**

Esta clase especificamente es la que me esta causando el error. Cuando busco por aca en la pagina, encuentro casos parecidos, pero la situacion y los metodos para resolverla me son dificiles de seguir por mi inexperiencia.

```
#include "Poligono.h"

class Triangulo : public Poligono{
    private:
        float lado1,lado2,lado3;
        
    public:
        Triangulo(float lado1,float lado2,float lado3){
            this->lado1 = lado1;
            this->lado2 = lado2;
            this->lado3 = lado3;
        }
        
        float perimetro(){
            float per = (lado1+lado2+lado3);
            return per;
        }
        
        float area (){
            float p = (lado1+lado2+lado3)/2;
            float area = (p*(p-lado1)*(p-lado2)*(p-lado3));
            return area;
        }
    
};
```

Cualquier ayuda sera enormemente agradecida!

Comment: Y que pasa si indicas explicitamente que los parametros son `float`? En lugar de `1`, pon `1.0F`.

Comment: ¿Qué compilador estás usando? Yo he compilado con GCC 11.1.0 y [compila sin problemas](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rHfmfFiwEcp8uMKD).

Answer (score 0):

Al llamar a tu constructor estás pasando constantes que el compilador toma como enteros (`int`):

```
poligonos[1] = new Triangulo(3,4,4);
```

Esto hace que trate de buscar un constructor que acepte tres parámentros de inicialización de tipo `int`, al no encontrarlo te tira el error que ves:

```
(Error) no matching function for call to 'Triangulo::Triangulo(int, int, int)'
```

Para definir una constante como flotante puedes usar un `.` o usar la letra `f` para ser aún más específico, así

```
poligonos[0] = new Rectangulo(7.0,4.0);
poligonos[1] = new Triangulo(3.0,4.0,4.0);
```

O así:

```
poligonos[0] = new Rectangulo(7.0f,4.0f);
poligonos[1] = new Triangulo(3.0f,4.0f,4.0f);
```

---

### UPDATE

¿Puedes utilizar variables flotantes para  crear la instancia de tu triangulo y ver que sucede? Así:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float a = 3;
    float b = 4;
    float c = 7;  
    Poligono* poligonos[2];
    
    poligonos[0] = new Rectangulo(c,b);
    poligonos[1] = new Triangulo(a,b,b);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias, pero acabo de intentar esa solucion y me sigue lanzando el mismo error :(

Comment: Uhm que extraño, te actualicé la respuesta con una prueba pequeña prueba para descartar del todo mi teoría. Prueba a ver si arregla tu problema.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el error es exactamente ese después de hacer el cambio? Mira que también tienes que hacer lo mismo con el rectángulo porque su constructor también funciona con flotantes.